# How to pass current location coordinates to the Geo-point that denotes source address in android application

Tags: android, mapquest

**I am working on my android project - a GPS based one ???**

Actually I got the information of current location, a location marker as the destination address.

Now i want to know how to map this current location as in location address/coordinates to the **Geo point** functionality in android. The current location would be the source address 
and **create a route** between these two points (source and destination).

Can anyone help me on this???

Thanks

Comment: didn't get exactly !!! you want your current location coordinates to be set as destination location???

Comment: No, i want to set current location (user location) as the source (starting address). since the current location keeps on changing based on the user, Send the coordinates (lat & values) into a function wouldnt be correct is what i think. I want to know how to map and the possible ways to do this???

Comment: can you show what have you done till now?? so that I can suggest based on that

Comment: Actually thank u so much i figured out.